# Sbt-native-packager produces two different packages on two different machines

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm building a debian package from scala project using the sbt-native-packager plugin. The package produced locally (macos) from command line has different size and of course md5sum than the one I produce in jenkins (debian) using the same sbt command:

```
sbt debian:packageBin
```

Also the jenkins produced debian package throws an error when using the included jar, like some classes were not included:

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster - User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shadeshapless/Generic
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: shadeshapless/Generic
```

I thought has to do something with the class names on debian environment so added the compiler option:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xmax-classfile-name","255")
```

I expect the same debian package to be produced on the local and jenkins environments.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting package will always depend on the machine as the version of the native build tool, in your case `deb-pkg`, affects how the package is produced. Sometimes a plugin generates code which might have timestamps that change, leading to different outputs.

Having said that. I personally hit this classfile issue with shading shapeless, sbt assembly and docker images. This however has nothing to do with the packaging.

Cheers,
Muki